# SSH keys not available when I re-open a project using VSCode SSH Remote

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I use VSCode with a remote SSH connection to modify my application code.

Before I start VSCode, I perform an `ssh-add` of my GitHub ssh key.

One of my VSCode remote workspaces is stuck in a state in which my github ssh key is not accessible.

Here is a sequence of steps that I have performed to troubleshoot this issue.

1. From my desktop, run `ssh-add -l`.  My github ssh key is available.
2. Open VSCode terminal. Run `ssh-add -l`.  My github ssh key is available.
3. Connect to a remote host in VSCode.  Open terminal. Run `ssh-add -l`.  My github ssh key is available.
4. Connect to the same remote host.  Open project folder X.  Open terminal. Run `ssh-add -l`.  **My github ssh key is not available.**

What can I do to reset/refresh my VSCode workspace for project folder X?

I have tried the following steps

- Run "Developer: Reload Window" in VSCode.  Repeat the steps above.  Same results.
- Quit VSCode.  Repeat the steps above.  Same results.
- Log out of my desktop.  Repeat the steps above.  Same results.